# Question about "how to make a decision" between offers should be reopened

Tags: discussion

[Choosing between two job offers: big brand vs smaller more fulfilling role](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/164553/choosing-between-two-job-offers-big-brand-vs-smaller-more-fulfilling-role)

The close reason says "Instead of asking which decision to make, *try asking how to make the decision*"

And the bolded, specific question says "How can I make a decision on which job to take?"

What are we trying to tell people by closing this question?

Comment: My 0.02 cents: If I omit the last line in the question and read it, I do not feel it's asking the "How can I make a decision" question, it's still "which decision shall I make".

Answer (score 2):

In my mind, this question is not well suited for this site, and answers will be heavily opinion based.  While the question is not so far over the line that I would "*mod hammer*" it closed, I also won't intervene.

If the community reopens it, so be it.

Comment: And yet, you did close it 1 hour ago, after it was reopened? "Closed 1 hour ago by gnat, Neo" (shrug)

Comment: @JoeStrazzere There is more to this than I can share sir.

Comment: Secrets? Oh well.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere I would not say secrets, the other moderators are aware.

Comment: Okay. So "not for the masses". I understand.

Comment: @Neo that phrase always get's my paranoia going.

Comment: @Old_Lamplighter It really shouldn't.  Sometimes people misbehave and we ( as mod's ) cannot discuss it.

Comment: @Neo things are discussed, just not in the open, thus the apprehension.   Given how a certain matter was handled a year ago, there isn't much trust left in SE, individual moderators, yes, but SE as a whole, no.  SE is transparent as obsidian.

Comment: @Old_Lamplighter But SE moderators have never divulged all the information behind an account getting suspended, not unless the suspended user has revealed the details first. That's not new.

Answer (score 0):

I am one of the original close-voters.

The way I read it, this is no different ask than:

> [2 Job Offers, one offering more 20% more money, but GUT FEELING telling me to take lower one](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/91180/2-job-offers-one-offering-more-20-more-money-but-gut-feeling-telling-me-to-ta)

or

> [How to decide between two life-changing career options?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/76709/how-to-decide-between-two-life-changing-career-options)

They are also somewhat well-received, but closed!

Comment: These two linked questions are somewhat different. The first asks "should I follow my gut?". That's not a question I'd vote to reopen. The second asks "what's the most rational way to decide which road to take?". If that question weren't over three years old, I'd happily vote to reopen.

Answer (score -1):

The question should not be reopened.

The point of how to make a decision vs asking about the decision isn't just to add "magic words" to the question to keep it open.  The OP has their list of pros and cons - the only meaningful "how" from here is "just decide" or some more byzantine "add points to each pro and con" kind of nonsense.  The "how" is "just do it" so the question reduces to "make the decision for me."